# pyspark load dataframe in bigquery from local

Tags: csv, dataframe, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to load a pyspark dataframe into a Google BigQuery table.

I run the job by running

```
spark-submit --jars batch/jars/gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar,batch/jars/spark-bigquery-latest.jar main_batch.py
```

I think I've set all the required configs:

```
sc = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .config("temporaryGcsBucket", "test_project_bucket_pyspark") \
        .config("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")\
        .config("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true") \
        .config("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "config/google/service_account_project.json") \
        .master("local[1]")\
        .appName("spark_etl")\
        .getOrCreate()
```

And I'm running this for saving into BigQuery:

```
df.write \
        .format("bigquery") \
        .option('table', 'dataset_project_test.tickets') \
        .option("encoding", "UTF-8") \
        .option("nullValue", "\u0000") \
        .option("emptyValue", "\u0000") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()
```

But I receive the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1176.save.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to add to your original spark config this entry `.config("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")` ?

Comment: Hi @mk_sta, thanks for your answer. By adding this config I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I assume that process or writing DataFrame to Bigquery certainly requires temporary GCS bucket to be defined as explained [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/README.md#writing-data-to-bigquery).

Therefore, I don't see in your code examples `temporaryGcsBucket` parameter defined inside `df.write` function for the particular Spark Bigquery [connector](http://temporaryGcsBucket) that might lead to the gs file system error.

You may try out either globally propagate `temporaryGcsBucket` parameter in Spark config (if you haven't done it yet):

```
spark.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', bucket)
```

Or adjusting it entirely in `df.write`:

```
df.write
  .....
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket")
  .save()
```

You can also check out the [reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/README.md#properties) list for adopted I/O Bigquery API parameters.

**Update:**

Assuming the fact that configuration parameter `.config("temporaryGcsBucket", "test_project_bucket_pyspark")` has been declared in `SparkSession` [settings](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession) as per code example, I can confirm that it would also be propagated in [SparkConf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties) runtime properties, that is a common approach here.

However, to further debug the issue you're facing I would recommend to check the configuration of Hadoop [connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/tree/master/gcs):

1. Ensure that all Hadoop related configs are properly loaded during Spark session execution, inspecting the error output for any  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` records;
2. If you have also any errors related to authorization, make sure that you have access to `temporaryGcsBucket` using `gsutil` (`gsutil ls -b gs://<some-bucket>`), and also verify that the credentials in your configuration are correct.
3. Try to add `fs.gs.project.id` parameter to the Spark runtime properties:

   `.config("fs.gs.project.id", "<MY_PROJECT>")`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If you see the code posted, I've configured the it in the SparkContext. .config("temporaryGcsBucket", "test_project_bucket_pyspark")

Comment: Yeah, you're right just figured it out. I've updated my answer, pls find more info there.